# How to run .html file in Flask? - Error Code 404

Tags: python, html, flask, assets

so my project structure is pretty straight-forward:

[image: Project structure]

Here is the code of my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Thus, the website should be build up properly with all designs (when I call the website through the browser-function inside of PyCharm, it loads all properly), but when doing it via app.py I get lots of 404 error like so:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:30] "GET /vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /css/grayscale.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /img/ipad.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /img/bg-masthead.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /js/grayscale.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /img/demo-image-01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /img/demo-image-02.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:31] "GET /vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2020 23:25:32] "GET /js/grayscale.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

All files are placed in the proper directories, otherwise it wouldn't work when using the inside-browser function, but I can't get why app.py doesn't GET those assets properly.

//EDIT: he index.html should work (prntscr.com/rkdz6k) when executing through the PyCharm browser function, the website loads properly, thus the template is correct. But somehow executing the .html through the app.py doesn't work

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: What's in your `index.html` template?

Comment: @Brian The index.html should work (http://prntscr.com/rkdz6k) when executing through the PyCharm browser function, the website loads properly, thus the template is correct. But somehow executing the .html through the app.py doesn't work.

Comment: Please post any updates to your question as an [edit]. It looks like your template uses both jQuery and bootstrap. Have your installed both of these frameworks and ensured that their files are accessible in your app's static root? Also, a minor quip: HTML isn't "executed" - its a markup language, i.e. just data which other software renders.

Comment: @Brian saved it in an edit above - as seen in the image above. I inserted the whole template data, speaking of css, img, js, vendor and index.html into templates; when referring to installing both of these frameworks how shall I do this in PyCharm with Flask?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation from wherever you got that `index.html` from. Instructions for how to install bootstrap can be found in the [project's website](https://getbootstrap.com/). This isn't at all related to Flask or PyCharm.

Comment: @Brian I disagree (though thanks for your reply once again) - Installing bootstrap and jQuery in PyCharm and integrating those properly in a Flask .py project is related to those topics you're denied them to be. In my opinion, that's why I posted it, this question is completely justified in the context I posted it. Even after doing a fair amount of research (on- and off-site) I haven't found a specific solution for my exact problem.

Comment: In that case, you may want update the title and body of your question to be a bit more informative, e.g. "How to install Bootstrap in PyCharm". At the moment I suspect that many users are ignoring your question since the current title makes it sound like your trying to "run an html file" and are confused why that does not work.

Comment: The title would be misleading as well, as I have already installed Bootstrap in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: All folders (as displayed above in the image) don't belong to the templates folder, they shall be part of the "static" folder. The templates folder only contains index.html whereas css, img, js and vendor (in my example (template)) was wrongly placed.

Now after dragging those 4 files into "static", everything executes with Code 200 and template loads up as it's supposed to do.